# Export data from SQL Server to Excel Using OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, export-to-excel

I'm trying to import data from SQL server to Excel spreadsheet using OpenRowSet function. My code works but it skips thousands of rows in the spreadsheet and insert the data from the 3665th row. Does anyone know how to fix this? Below is the code I executed:

```
USE webemt;
GO
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0           Xml;HDR=YES;Database=c:\AccreditedProgramsRpt_02042015.xlsx;',
    'SELECT * FROM [AccreditedPrograms$]')
    SELECT Programs.Name,   
    Programs.ProgramCode,   
    Programs.StateCode,   
    Programs.IsAccredited,   
    Programs.HasLetterOfReview,   
    FROM Programs  
    WHERE Programs.Status in (1,2) 
    order by Programs.Name asc
    GO
```

Also enclosed is a screenshot of the excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the `where` clause is doing what you actually want it to?

Are the values in `Programs.Status` integers and not strings?

Also have you tried it without the `order by` to see if that's having any effect?

Comment: I figured it out. It had nothing to do with the code. I had to delete the and re-create the worksheet before running the code.